# Get username from passwd file using shell scripting

Tags: regex, perl, shell, awk

From `/etc/passwd`, I need just the "user" part.

Example:

```
backup:x:34:34:backup:/var/backups:/bin/sh
```

has `backup` as the user.

To extract the user part I am using this now:

```
perl -pe 's/^(.*?):.*/\1/g' < /etc/passwd
```

which is a few characters less than my old method:

```
while read line; do echo ${line%%:*}; done < /etc/passwd
```

but it sounds like an overkill. It's a lot of text to write.

A Google search gives me:

```
awk -F  ':' '{print $1}' < /etc/passwd
```

which is equivalent, I suppose? Is it?

```
cmp <(perl -pe 's/^(.*?):.*/\1/g' < /etc/passwd) <(awk -F  ':' '{print $1}' < /etc/passwd)
```

Is there a standard UNIX tool to do this or an easier method using perl? Or `cut`?

I am a beginner.

BTW, I tried my hand at Python as follows but I suck at it, there may be better ways to do this in Python `:(`

```
python -c 'print "\n".join([u[:u.find(":")] for u in open("/etc/passwd")])'
```

EDIT: actually, maybe more like this for Python:

```
python -c 'print "\n".join([u.split(":")[0] for u in open("/etc/passwd")])'
```

Hmm... still very verbose.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
perl -F: -lane 'print $F[0]' < /etc/passwd
```

does nore-or-less what the `awk` solution does. `-a` means split each line of input into fields, `-F:` means that `:` is the field delimiter. And the `-l` outputs a newline for each line of input so you don't have to say `print "$F[0]\n"`.

Since you requested it, the `cut` solution is even more straightforward:

```
cut -d: -f1 < /etc/passwd
```

Meaning: split on `:`, output the first field.

Comment: Mamma mia, that `cut` one-liner is just awesome, man. I was doing it all wrong!

Answer (score 6):

Personally, I would use the awk solution. Cut works, but I often find it not quite flexible enough.

```
awk -F: '{print $1}' /etc/passwd
```

Or, more generically, use `getent passwd`. This will query all the user DB sources configured in `/etc/nsswitch.conf`, which could be stuff like remote LDAP servers (and also `/etc/passwd`).

```
getent passwd | awk -F: '{print $1}'
```

If you want a bash-only solution, you could do this. It's weird looking, but it doesn't invoke any external commands. Setting the inter-field separator `$IFS` tells `read` what characters to split on. The `< /etc/passwd` redirection at the end takes effect for the entire loop.

```
while IFS=: read USER _; do
    echo "$USER"
done < /etc/passwd
```

(Setting `$IFS` this way only affects the `read` command. Generally, you can put variable assignments before any command and they'll only be in effect for that command. For example:

```
$ FOO=foo
$ echo $FOO
foo
$ FOO=bar true
$ echo $FOO
foo
```

So no worries about messing up `$IFS`.)

Comment: @Robottinosino Fixed, forgot to put `IFS=:`.

Comment: I am also worried about overwriting the system $USER variable? :( *AND* changing IFS? :(

Comment: @Robottinosino Every script gets its own environment, so changing `$USER` would be local to your script. Of course you can use any variable name you like, there.

Comment: Fair enough. I just meant to type that into the CLI though, not to use that as a separate script. That's the confusion..

Comment: Bash variables are case-sensitive, so leave the ALLUPPERCASE names to the shell. `read user _` works just as well, and avoids overwriting `USER` in any shell.

Answer (score 1):

Perl provides a built-in to do this for you: [getpwent](http://search.cpan.org/dist/perl/pod/perlfunc.pod#getpwent)

```
endpwent(); # reset to beginning of file in case some other code has read some entries already
while ( my ($username) = getpwent() ) { 
    print "user: $username\n";
}
endpwent();
```

getpwuid and getpwnam can be used to look up a particular name or id; all three get functions return a list of all the standard fields on a line.

Answer (score 1):

If all you need is the user name, the `id' command will suffice and is much simpler.

```
USER=`id -un`
```

For other parts of the password file entry, I would still use one of the above options.